# How to permanently get rid of the Yahoo Extension overlay

Tags: yahoo-mail, google-chrome-extensions

For about a week now, every time I log in to Yahoo Mail from Chrome an overlay appears asking me to install an extension, in order to “get the full Yahoo experience in Chrome”. How do I get rid of it permanently? *Without* installing the extension, obviously.

[image]

Comment: Looks like their is no option without installing the extension, like Overlay Blocker and BehindTheOverlay will get rid of ads and also having shortcut key "Ctrl-Shift-x" to remove the ad automatically from the page.

Comment: I don't appear to get this "overlay" (yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kilrplatypus' solution is almost perfect. However, it has the sub-subdomain names in the rules (`us-mg5`) which is not constant.

The more general filter rules are:

```
mail.yahoo.com###uh-dmos-msgbox  
mail.yahoo.com##.uh-dmos-msgbox  
mail.yahoo.com###uh-dmos-overlay  
mail.yahoo.com##.uh-dmos-overlay  
mail.yahoo.com###uh-dmos-wrapper
```

BTW, I just used it on a client's computer and took care of this annoying popup very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

If you use AdBlock Plus, add the following to your "Add Your Own Filters" list:

```
us-mg5.mail.yahoo.com###uh-dmos-msgbox  
us-mg5.mail.yahoo.com##.uh-dmos-msgbox  
us-mg5.mail.yahoo.com###uh-dmos-overlay  
us-mg5.mail.yahoo.com##.uh-dmos-overlay  
us-mg5.mail.yahoo.com###uh-dmos-wrapper
```

That covers all the pop-up related elements.  That last one (wrapper) prevents clicking within the email window.

Answer (score 1):

I use the AdBlock Plus extension to do this - when you log in to your Yahoo Mail, wait for the annoying overlay to appear, then click on your AdBlock Plus icon.  Select the option for "block element", then (left) click on the overlay.  AdBlock will then block that element of the pop up.  There are several of these elements in this pop up, so you need to repeat the process of selecting "block element", clicking on the parts of the overlay which are still visible.  When I did this, there was one final "hidden" element which you can't see but stops the screen from being responsive.  Again, just select "block element", click anywhere on the unresponsive screen and that should be it.  Once you have your normal, fully functioning yahoo mail home screen back you're fixed.  AdBlock Plus will remember to block the overlay in the future and you won't see it again.

I believe there's also a Chrome extension called "overlay blocker" which can do the same thing, although I haven't used this myself.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this is called an overlay or popup module.

There's a Chrome extension called [Overlay Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/overlay-blocker/inncfpkneoefpgnoggjhcnkjhbcdeimo) on the Chrome Web Store that deletes these popups automatically.